# How to solve Unsatisfied Link Error when running a jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, scenebuilder

**I am trying to create a custom scene builder 2.0 component**. In order to do that, I downloaded the source of one of oracle's javaFX component samples, in this case, *ServiceSample.java*:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 2012 Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
 */

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;    
import javafx.stage.Stage;    
import java.util.Date;    
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;    
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;    
import javafx.concurrent.Service;    
import javafx.concurrent.Task;    
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;    
import javafx.event.EventHandler;    
import javafx.geometry.Insets;    
import javafx.scene.control.Button;    
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;    
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;    
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;    
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;    
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;    
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;    
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;    

/**    
 * A sample showing use of a Service to retrieve data in a background thread.    
 * Selecting the Refresh button restarts the Service.    
 *    
 * @see javafx.collections.FXCollections    
 * @see javafx.concurrent.Service    
 * @see javafx.concurrent.Task    
 * @see javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator    
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableColumn    
 * @see javafx.scene.control.TableView    
 */

public class ServiceSample extends Application {    

    final GetDailySalesService service = new GetDailySalesService();    

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {    
        Group root = new Group();    
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));    
        VBox vbox = new VBox(5);    
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(12));    
        TableView tableView = new TableView();    
        Button button = new Button("Refresh");    
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {   
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {    
                service.restart();    
            }    
        });

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(tableView, button);     

        Region veil = new Region();    
        veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)");    
        ProgressIndicator p = new ProgressIndicator();    
        p.setMaxSize(150, 150);     

        //Define table columns    
        TableColumn idCol = new TableColumn();

        idCol.setText("ID");    
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("dailySalesId"));    
        tableView.getColumns().add(idCol);    
        TableColumn qtyCol = new TableColumn();    
        qtyCol.setText("Qty");    
        qtyCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("quantity"));    
        tableView.getColumns().add(qtyCol);    
        TableColumn dateCol = new TableColumn();    
        dateCol.setText("Date");    
        dateCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("date"));    
        dateCol.setMinWidth(240);    
        tableView.getColumns().add(dateCol);     

        p.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());    
        veil.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());    
        p.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());    
        tableView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());     

        StackPane stack = new StackPane();    
        stack.getChildren().addAll(vbox, veil, p);    

        root.getChildren().add(stack);    
        service.start();    
    }    

    /**    
     * A service for getting the DailySales data. This service exposes an    
     * ObservableList for convenience when using the service. This    
     * <code>results</code> list is final, though its contents are replaced when    
     * a service call successfully concludes.    
     */

    public class GetDailySalesService extends Service<ObservableList<DailySales>> {   

        /**    
         * Create and return the task for fetching the data. Note that this    
         * method is called on the background thread (all other code in this    
         * application is on the JavaFX Application Thread!).    
         *    
         * @return A task    
         */

        @Override    
        protected Task createTask() {    
            return new GetDailySalesTask();    
        }    
    }    

    public class GetDailySalesTask extends Task<ObservableList<DailySales>> {           
        @Override protected ObservableList<DailySales> call() throws Exception {

            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {    
                updateProgress(i, 500);    
                Thread.sleep(5);    
            }

            ObservableList<DailySales> sales = FXCollections.observableArrayList();    
            sales.add(new DailySales(1, 5000, new Date()));    
            sales.add(new DailySales(2, 2473, new Date(0)));    
            return sales;    
        }
     }



    public class DailySales {     

        private Integer dailySalesId;    
        private Integer quantity;    
        private Date date;     

        public DailySales() {

        }

        public DailySales(int id, int qty, Date date) {

            this.dailySalesId = id;    
            this.quantity = qty;    
            this.date = date;    
        }   

        public Integer getDailySalesId() {    
            return dailySalesId;    
        }     

        public void setDailySalesId(Integer dailySalesId) {

            this.dailySalesId = dailySalesId;    
        }



        public Integer getQuantity() {    
            return quantity;    
        }



        public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {    
            this.quantity = quantity;    
        }  

        public Date getDate() {    
            return date;    
        }

        public void setDate(Date date) {    
            this.date = date;    
        }    
    }     

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {    
        init(primaryStage);    
        primaryStage.show();    
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }    
}
```

I added the *jfxrt.jar*(that contains javaFX classes) to the build path of this project and it worked fine in the IDE I'm using - *eclipse*. I exported the ServiceSample as a *runnable jar* but it isn't working outside eclipse. I tried running the command `java -jar ServiceSample.jar` on the cmdline but I keep getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Application launch error
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:122)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._invokeLater(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._invokeLater(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.invokeLater(Application.java:338)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.defer(QuantumToolkit.java:620)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:173)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runAndWait(PlatformImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.tkExit(PlatformImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:421)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Any particular reason your code has spaces between every single line?

Comment: Not really, the formatting got like that after I copy+pasted. Tried to edit it so it hasn't so many spaces @Jashaszun